# Printing with Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, view, printing

I have a view named Details, and it gets its data from invoke method of the controller based on search criteria. I have a print button in the Details view and when I press it I want to pass the searched data to the print view as below:

```
class ProductSerialNoWiseLedgerController extends Controller
{

    public function __invoke()
    {
        $searchParameters = request()->only([
            'machineries_ID',
            'hospital_ID',
            'project_ID',
            'batchNo',
            'unit_ID',
            'DR',
            'CR',
            'Balance',
        ]);




        $query = Hospital_Stocks_SerialNoWise::with('hospitals', 'project', 'unit', 'machinery')
            ->orderBy('id');

        // Apply search parameters
        foreach ($searchParameters as $field => $value) {
            if ($value !== null) {
                if ($field === 'machineries_ID') {
                    $query->whereHas('machinery', function ($subQuery) use ($value) {
                        $subQuery->where('en_name', 'like', '%' . $value . '%');
                    });
                } elseif ($field === 'hospital_ID') {
                    $query->whereHas('hospitals', function ($subQuery) use ($value) {
                        $subQuery->where('en_name', 'like', '%' . $value . '%');
                    });
                } elseif ($field === 'project_ID') {
                    $query->whereHas('project', function ($subQuery) use ($value) {
                        $subQuery->where('en_name', 'like', '%' . $value . '%');
                    });
                } elseif ($field === 'unit_ID') {
                    $query->whereHas('unit', function ($subQuery) use ($value) {
                        $subQuery->where('en_name', 'like', '%' . $value . '%');
                    });
                } else {
                    $query->where('hospital__stocks__serial_no_wises.' . $field, 'like', '%' . $value . '%');
                }
            }
        }
        if (request()->has('print')) {
        $properties = $query->get();

        
        return view('Details.Stocks.printProductSNWLedger')->with(['data' => $properties]);
    }

        if (isset(request()->per_page)) {
            $perPage = in_array(request('per_page'), getPerPageOptions()) ? \request('per_page') : 10;
            $properties = $query->paginate($perPage);
        } else {
            $properties = $query->get();

        }

        return response()->json(['data' => $properties]);
    }

   
}
```

For the details view the search works fine, but it passes all the data  to the print view instead of searched data when print button is clicked.
Here is my route:

```
Route::get('printProductSNWLedger', [\App\Http\Controllers\Details\Stocks\ProductSerialNoWiseLedgerController::class, '__invoke']);
```

and here is my print function in the front:

```
const handlePrint = () => {
  window.open('printProductSNWLedger?print=1', '_blank');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not passing search parameters when requesting the route with print button. for example your printing section in js should be like this:

```
const handlePrint = () => {
     window.open('printProductSNWLedger?print=1&machineries_ID=227', '_blank');
};
```

in the above code you see I've included `machineries_ID=227` in the query string so it would be applied

Comment: Thank you sir, still don't know why I didn't work for the previous version.